# MongoDB managing index for many fields in one collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

In MongoDB we can create index for particular fields that get the accurate data. But what if we have a scenario like `"Book_Features"` collection below?

In this collection every fields is given for users to sort and list the items they required. How do we index this fields? Should we index all the fields in this collection? Is that a good idea?

**Books**

```
_id, book_name, description, price, quantity, author
```

**Book_Features**

```
_id, 
book_id, 
format: [pdf, ebook, hard-copy], 
hard_copy: [soft-bind, hard-bind],
category: [fantasy, horror, adventurous],
languages: [English, Kannada, Hindi],
reviews: {[user: user_id, stars: 5, comment: '', date: '']},
released: [2015, 03, 16],
volumes: [1, 2, 3],
total_pages: 200,
.... and more ....
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you intent is but there are [limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations) to what you can do with compound indexes here. If really depends on your query patterns.

Comment: If your query limited the number of results, you can sort without an index within acceptable time. Combined with pagination, this should be enough to fulfill speed requirements. I fail to see the point of maintaining a books features in a separate collection, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to improve the performance when user sorts data based on the above fields.
In general it is not a good idea to make so many fields as index, but if you have more data which is being retrieved based on then above search terms and if this are very frequently used terms in the query you can go ahead and make them all as index.